# I get a fatal error when I use an Insert Into statement with parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, database, image, fatal-error

I'm trying to add a row into a mysql database table using visual studio 2010 and I haven't had problems until now. I keep getting the error:

> "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

Table structure:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `magazine_images` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MagazineKey` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `image` blob,
  `image_size` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `image_ctgy` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `image_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`),
  KEY `image_magazine` (`MagazineKey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

C Sharp query:

```
string image = "INSERT INTO magazine_images (MagazineKey, image, image_type, image_size, image_ctgy, image_name) " +
                    "VALUES(@magkey, @image, @image_type, @image_size, @image_ctgy, @image_name)";
            this.cmd = new MySqlCommand(putImage, this.con);
            this.read = this.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            this.read.Read();
            this.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@magkey", int.Parse(labelKey.Text));
            this.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", textBoxImageFile.Text);
            this.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_name", textBoxImageName.Text);
            this.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_type", comboBoxImageType.Text);
            this.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_ctgy", textBoxImageCategory.Text);
            this.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_size", labelImageSize.Text);
            this.read.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your code is incomplete or you are currently adding your query parameters **after** you execute the query - you have to do it before the query executes.

Also you are not even using the `image` variable - you are using `putImage` which you haven't shown. Thirdly you should not use `ExecuteReader()` - this is for retrieving only, but you are doing an insertion, for that you need `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

In summary: Either you have a lot of copy & paste errors or your sample does not reflect your real code.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not notice that I was adding parameters after executing. Thank you very much for catching that. And yeah, I changed 'putImage' to 'image' when I was copying the code for some reason. I need to sleep.

Also, thanks for telling me about the ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery methods. I learned C# this summer and I'm still learning.